# WebAPI2 and MVC5 route config

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5, config

I have coded a C# ASP.net MVC5 internet application that works well and I can do CRUD operations using a `Person` model.

I have added a WebAPI2 controller that uses the entity framework but am getting errors when trying to browse to any of the WebAPI controller methods.

The WebAPI2 controller is called `PersonAPIController`. The `Getpeople` method has the `// GET api/PersonAPI` comment above the method, yet when browsing to this method, I am getting this error:

> The resource cannot be found.

Is this a routing issue?

I have a `RouteConfig` and a `WebApiConfig`. Do these two configs need to be combined?

Here is the contents of  `RouteConfig`:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Here is the contents of `WebApiConfig`:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Currently, this is my `Application_Start` method:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Does the `WebApiConfig.Register()` line of code need to be added before the `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)`?

If so, what is the parameter that need to be added to the `WebApiConfig.Register()` method?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Here is the exact code to use:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that to call `Register(HttpConfiguration config)` before `RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)`.  The sequence matters.

Answer (score 0):

Call /api/personapi rather than /api/personapi/getpeople